# PHP : How to set array Value with $_GET

Tags: php, url, get

i  tried to set the value of the $_GET[] into an array object

this is my code

```
$X=array(
'status_1'=>'"'.$_GET['hasil_1'].'"',
'status_2'=>'"'.$_GET['hasil_2'].'"',
'status_3'=>'"'.$_GET['hasil_3'].'"',
.
.
'status_17'=>'"'.$_GET['hasil_17'].'"');

//Faktor Klasifikasi
$n = 'derajat';

//nama tabel
$table='tabel';

classify($X,$n,$table);
```

it's not working .

this is the url

```
http://localhost:8080/tugas/sispak/hasil.php?hasil_1=1&hasil_2=1&hasil_3=1&hasil_4=1&hasil_5=1&hasil_6=0&hasil_7=1&hasil_8=1&hasil_9=0&hasil_10=1&hasil_11=1&hasil_12=1&hasil_13=1&hasil_14=1&hasil_15=1&hasil_16=1&hasil_17=1
```

but , if i write it manualy like

```
$Y=array(
'status_1'=>'1',
'status_2'=>'1',
'status_3'=>'1',

.
.
'status_17'=>'1'
);
```

it works !!

this is where I handle the values of my array

```
//var_dump($allclass);
    foreach($allclass as $c=>$p)
    {
        foreach($X as $x=>$y)
        {
            $i = mysql_query("select count(*) as num from ".$table." where ".$n."='".$c."' AND ".$x."='".$y."'");
            $j = mysql_fetch_array($i,MYSQL_ASSOC);

            $P[$c][$x] = round($j["num"]/$allclass[$c],2);

    //Exception: P(data/class) might be 0 in some cases, ignore 0 for now
            if($P[$c][$x] != 0)
                $argmax[$c] *= $P[$c][$x];
        }
        $argmax[$c] *= $Pc[$c];
    }
```

somebody help me ,please

Comment: you're doing `'status_1' => '"foo"'`, with extra quotes.

Comment: _"it's not working"_ Never think that this is an acceptable problem description. And if you'd just printed out your MySQL query you'd have seen the problem......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need all those quotes, try as follows:

```
$X = array(
    'status_1'=> $_GET['hasil_1'],
    'status_2'=> $_GET['hasil_2'],
    'status_3'=> $_GET['hasil_3']
);
```